# Can't wrap a Menu.Item with Link

Tags: node.js, reactjs, antd, next.js

I'm currently using a [`Menu`](https://ant.design/components/menu/) for my main header navigation, with [`Menu.Item`](https://ant.design/components/menu/#Menu.Item) components for the individual menu items.

At the moment, the code looks like so:

```js
<Menu>
    <Menu.Item>
        <span className="nav-text">
            <Link href="/login">
                <a>Login</a>
            </Link>
        </span>
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>
        <span className="nav-text">
            <Link href="/register">
                <a>Register</a>
            </Link>
        </span>
    </Menu.Item>
</Menu>
```

Which makes the `Login` and `Register` spans clickable, but not the menu items themselves. When trying to move the [`Link`](https://nextjs.org/docs/#with-link) and `a` tags upwards to include the entire `Menu.Item` -

```js
<Menu>
    <Link href="/login">
        <a>
            <MenuItem>
                <span className="nav-text">
                    Login
                </span>
            </MenuItem>
        </a>
    </Link>
    <Link href="/register">
        <a>
            <MenuItem>
                <span className="nav-text">
                    Register
                </span>
            </MenuItem>
        </a>
    </Link>
</Menu>
```

The entire menu gets hidden and replaced with `···`:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm not sure how to fix this and make the menu render correctly with the menu items clickable, and so I'd love to get some help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue fixed itself somehow, and earlier I bumped into another issue I can't reproduce at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using React than you can wrap the Menu.Item Component around the Link tag.

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
...
  <Link to="#">
    <Menu.Item>Your Content</Menu.Item> 
  </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the hook "useRouter" from 'next/router' to manage linking where Link is not enough.

In this case you can use router.push({YOUR_ROUTE}) inside the onClick event of <Menu.Item />.

```
import React from 'react';
import {useRouter} from 'next/router';
import {Menu} from 'antd';

const UsingRouterHook: React.FC = () => {

    const router = useRouter();

    return (
        <Menu mode="horizontal" onClick={() => router.push('/login')}>
            <Menu.Item key="login" >
                <span className="nav-text">Login</span>
            </Menu.Item>

            <Menu.Item key="register" onClick={() => router.push('/register')}>
                <span className="nav-text">Register</span>
            </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
    );
}

export default UsingRouterHook;
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. The menu item should be a real `<a href="...` and not something that partially fulfils that role. The user should be able to right-click and 'copy link', 'open in new tab', etc.

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax for Link component is invalid. you should use like this:
`<Link to="/register">Register</Link>`

change your code to this:

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
...
      <Menu mode="horizontal">
        <Menu.Item key="login">
          <Link to="/login">
            <span className="nav-text">Login</span>
          </Link>
        </Menu.Item>

        <Menu.Item key="register">
          <Link to="/register">
            <span className="nav-text">Register</span>
          </Link>
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
```

Comment: He is using [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/) ``Link`` Component, not  from ``react-router-dom``.

Comment: I didn't see the next.js tag but, this example work in antd properly.

Comment: This makes the menu render properly, but it also makes the menu items unclickable 
and so the routing doesn't work.